# How to disable touch screen with a broken screen?

Tags: touchscreen

I have a lenovo yoga pro 2. I´ve closed it badly and now i have the screen broken. It has one crack at the bottom which does imitates clicks on the screen. I did not found any hot keys to disable touch on screen. The only solution i found is to go to the device manager and disable it there. But because of the crack which does like 6 touches per second i can't open it and do something there.
Is there any easy solution to disable it in this situation?

Comment: Did you try booting in safe mode? The driver might be disabled then.

Comment: Touch is active even on the menu to select the save mode options ;) and in save mode also